# How to create a table with php variable as table name?

Tags: php, mysql

Hi I am trying to create a table like '$username'_package in google mysql cloud. I could create table successfully but it actually create a table with name like this say `'.aaa@gmail.com.'_pakage` but I actually need to create a table with name like `aaa@gmail.com_package`. 
This my query,

```
mysql_query("CREATE TABLE `db`.`{$email_append}` (`id` int(25) NOT NULL,`packageid` int(25) NOT NULL,`package_name` varchar(35) NOT NULL,`category` varchar(24) NOT NULL,`description` varchar(24) NOT NULL,`sub_description` varchar(25) NOT NULL,`default_price` int(25) NOT NULL,`custom_price` int(25) NOT NULL,`force_amount` int(25) NOT NULL,`percent_discount` int(25) NOT NULL,`package_total` int(25) NOT NULL)");
```

These are the try that I have made,

```
1.'".$username."'
2.'$username'
3.`$username`
4.I created a php variable "$email_append" and concat it with "_package".
```

Every try gave me the same results. How to solve this. Can someone help me? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can concat like that:

```
`db`.`{".$email."_append}`
```

**Example:**

```
$email = 'test';
echo "CREATE TABLE `db`.`".$email."_append` (`id` int(25) NOT NULL,`packageid` int(25) NOT NULL,`package_name` varchar(35) NOT NULL,`category` varchar(24) NOT NULL,`description` varchar(24) NOT NULL,`sub_description` varchar(25) NOT NULL,`default_price` int(25) NOT NULL,`custom_price` int(25) NOT NULL,`force_amount` int(25) NOT NULL,`percent_discount` int(25) NOT NULL,`package_total` int(25) NOT NULL)";
```

**Result:**

```
CREATE TABLE `db`.`test_append` 
(
`id` INT(25) NOT NULL,
`packageid` INT(25) NOT NULL,
`package_name` VARCHAR(35) NOT NULL,
`category` VARCHAR(24) NOT NULL,
`description` VARCHAR(24) NOT NULL,
`sub_description` VARCHAR(25) NOT NULL,
`default_price` INT(25) NOT NULL,
`custom_price` INT(25) NOT NULL,
`force_amount` INT(25) NOT NULL,
`percent_discount` INT(25) NOT NULL,
`package_total` INT(25) NOT NULL
)
```

**Issue:**

In your code `{$email_append}` its treated as a full variable, which is not you need to concat `$email` and `_append`.

**Side Note:**

Please use `mysqli_*` or `PDO` instead of `mysql_*` its deprecated and not available in PHP 7.

Comment: That worked fine for me and you have helped me identify my mistake... @devpro

Comment: glad to help u @Anu: :)